# Build,Install,Execute an application without using XCode

Tags: iphone, shell, xcodebuild

I would like to build, install and execute an xcode project on device but without using XCode GUI. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.
Niko

[EDIT]
And what about an IPA? is it possible to install, execute an IPA application without using iTunes, only with shell commands?

[EDIT 2]
or maybe using Automator?

Comment: I know how to compile the App using xcodebuild command, but I'm not able to install the app on device and execute it.

Comment: You can always install what you compiled using iTunes. That is, if you've signed the binary properly. I don't think there is a way to do the install from the command line.

Comment: Do you think it might be done with a jailbreaked iPhone?

Comment: FYI, I found a way to do it using AppleScript. Found it on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995424/xcode-test-automation-for-iphone/3812359#3812359